# How to make an empty element in array be considered non existing in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, count, element

```
$var1=1; $var2=2; $var3='';
$array= array ( $var1 , $var2, $var3 );

echo count($array);
// Result (3)
```

I want the count result to be (2) and if possible without looping. 
I wonder if there's a way since I assume there are 3 keys counted. How do I eliminate the key with an empty value? This can simplify a lot of things to me.

Comment: `count(array_filter($array));`

Comment: *"and if possible without looping"* Why, just why?!

Comment: nice, but is it possible to tell call_user_func_array() to see things that way without sending:  Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number ...?

Comment: @alexis That's not coming from `call_user_func_array`, that's coming frim `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`. The first argument is a string with the types of each placeholder, and the number of arguments has to match the size of that string.

Comment: That's why i was trying to unset the variable corresponding to a bind type (i) and to a (?) portion of the query string that i both dynamically remove. Still the corresponding  variable  even set to empty is counted despite its type and string portion no longer exist, and the error persisting.  @Kris Roofe proposition was the keypoint to solve the problem by unsetting automatically the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

unset():

```
$var1=1; $var2=2; $var3='';
$array= array ( $var1 , $var2, $var3 );
unset($array[2]);

echo count($array);
```

Comment: I'm trying to exploit your way, looks like this could help

Comment: Your case helped the most to solve my problem. Thank you, but also thanks to all who tried to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_filter to only keep the values that are non-empty in the array, like this:

```
array_filter($array);
```

So, to count only non-empty:

```
count(array_filter($array));
```

For the problem you mentioned in the comments. see if this helps:

suppose you have following array and a uery `$sql`:

```
$arr ="$name, $pass, $email, $contact, $company";
$result = $connection->prepare("$sql");
$newarr = array_merge( (array) $types, $arr);
call_user_func_array(array($result, 'bind_param'), $newarr);
```

Comment: Any way to tell call_user_func_array() to see things that way while binding parameters and prevent error: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of of bind variables...?